# Array as lookup value in Vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am looking to work out the sum commission on different products based on different scenarios and prices.

The cumbersome way to do this is to create a different sheet with the range of products and then use the vlookup in a normal fashion to get the correct commission:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$A$10:$B$18,2,TRUE)
```

[image: Example]
What I am trying do to us use this range to work out commission across multiple product specs (100's) by using a `sumproduct` and nested `vlookups` in the following manner:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP({75,20,154,98,315},$A$10:$B$18,2,TRUE)*{75,20,154,98,315})
```

But this seems to only multiply the first commission % out over the range:

```
=0.007*{75,20,154,98,315}
=4.63
```

Instead of the correct `6`

Comment: `=315*0.95%` is `2.9925` which is rounded `2.99` and not `3.00`. And the sum of `C2:C6` is **not** `6` but `5.53` in your example. Please clarify.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` cannot be used with array as lookup value. `LOOKUP` can. So `=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP({75,20,154,98,315},A11:A18,B11:B18)*{75,20,154,98,315})`. But your rounding looks strange.

Comment: @AxelRichter, thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry, for causing confusion with the rounding of the 5.52 to 6. The concept was a lot more important that the little toy example.